# Can I use Vuejs Material Dashboard template on Nuxtjs App?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

As a beginner I am trying to use a  free template of  Vuejs version of the Original Material Dashboard template on existing Nuxtjs project. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a messy way to do thing. Just create a new Nuxt project, then copy paste the things you need to keep from your vuejs folder (components for example, do not copy paste everything of course)